# How to allow user picture during registration?

Tags: 7, media

I have the [Avatar Selection](https://www.drupal.org/project/avatar_selection) module and the [Register with Picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module installed.

But I can't get the file chooser to show up on the registration page.

What would be the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to use the [Register with Picture](https://drupal.org/project/reg_with_pic) module.

I've never experience any problem with this module.

You install it and configure it, and it does what it is supposed to do.

> This module exposes the 'upload picture' element to the registration form. It also gives you the ability to set a picture as required in the module settings.

You will be given a check box at *admin/config/people/accounts* named "Enable user pictures on registration" and weight selection. Make sure you also check "Enable user pictures".

[image]

This is how it should look like when a new user tries to register:

[image]

Comment: I have that module installed... Anonymous users have peemission to upload their picture, but there's still no file upload widget... Could something else be blocking it?

Comment: @brainstormtrooper did you follow the installation directions fully on the project page?

Comment: Yes, there weren't many "instructions"... Axtivate the module and then check the box for the image field... I did that...

Comment: @brainstormtrooper, weird - I've never had any problems with this module. As you say, it is not much to configure.  The only thing I can think of is that there is some conflict with another module.  Try disabling other modules, starting with **Avatar selection**.

Comment: Well, that did it... I deactivated avatar selection and i now have a file select widget - but I need both :-( I'll try putting back avatar selection...

Comment: THANK YOU Free Radical!!! When i re-enabled avatar selection it worked, but there is no check box for it anymore (in the config).... But i do have the widget on the sign up form :-)